# Returning dynamic memory inside a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, return-value, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hi I have the following struct

```c
typedef struct mystruct_s {
    int* array;
} mystruct;
```

and I want to create a function that initializes it.
I have two ways of doing it.

First one is:

```c
mystruct new_mystruct()
{
    mystruct tmp;
    tmp.array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

    return tmp;
}
```

Second one is:

```c
mystruct* new_mystruct()
{
    mystruct* tmp = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    tmp->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

    return tmp;
}
```

I want to know which one is the better approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better in terms of?

Comment: Both are valid. Either one can be better/more suitable, depending on what exactly you are doing. "Dynamic memory inside" is a red herring. The answer doesn't really depend on whether the struct contains a pointer to allocated memory.

Comment: There's a 3rd approach: `int new_mystruct(mystruct *m) { m->array = ... }`

Comment: Both are correct. However, you will find that in libraries, you will almost never encounter the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general rule of thumb is to never pass structs by value, mainly for performance reasons. The first version should be avoided for that reason.

Regarding the second version, then there's some more advanced issues. Multiple calls to `malloc()` have the following problems:

- Each call comes with execution overhead of its own.
- Each call may give a different segment, causing heap segmentation over time = poor usage of memory.
- Allocations in different segments means poor utilization of data cache on CPUs that support it.
- You need to make multiple calls to `free()` as well. Again extra execution overhead and the potential of memory leaks if you don't call it multiple times.

A better method is to use flexible array members:

```c
typedef struct {
  size_t size
  int array[];
} mystruct;

size_t n = 123;
mystruct* ms = malloc( sizeof *ms + sizeof(int[n]) );
ms->size = n;
memcpy(ms->array, data, sizeof(int[n]));
...
free(ms);
```

This is faster and less complex all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Both implementation are good, the first one uses heap memory by calling `malloc()` once which means you need to `free()` only once.

Whereas, in the second implementation, it uses heap memory by calling `malloc()` twice, so you need to call `free()` twice, which leads to additional calls to `free()` later in your code.

*NOTE: Number of calls to `malloc()` should be equal to number of calls to `free()`. But in modern operating systems, sometimes freeing the heap allocated resources isn't needed, OS manage them accordingly.*

Comment: What do you mean by "always freeing the heap allocated resources is not needed, they manage them accordingly"? C is not a garbage-collected language.

Comment: @ThomasJager `they` --> `operating systems`

Comment: The operating system being able to reuse memory after a process terminates doesn't mean that you shouldn't `free` memory when you're done with it. Allocations aren't freed because we're worried the OS will run out of memory after the program has exited, it's during execution that resources are consumed.

Comment: @ThomasJager OP hasn't said he's using the block of memory for a long time

Comment: The main reason why you should always call free() explicitly is because it exposes dormant pointer heap corruption bugs. A crash during free() means there's a bug somewhere. It's a way to ensure that your program stays bug free and bugs surface during development, not some years later in full production.

Comment: @Lundin I have also written **Number of calls to `malloc()` should be equal to number of calls to `free()`.**

Comment: @Darth-CodeX You've also explicitly said that freeing allocated resources is not needed, which contradicts that.

Answer (score -2):

I read the OP question wrong.  I appreciate the comments pointing out my issue and making a better post.  Here is an example of an array in a struct and a pointer in a struct.  It also shows how the two variants differ in memory layout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct one {
  int start;
  char pch[5];
  int end;
};

struct two {
  int start;
  char *pch;
  int end;
};

int main() {

  // Sizeof types
  // char 1 bytes/8-bits
  // int  4 bytes/32-bits
  // pointers 8 bytes/64-bits
  //                                              // Vars on stack in main frame.
  int main_start = 1;                             // &main_start = 0x7ffe74ad0b48
  struct one *pOne;                               // &pOne = 0x7ffe74ad0b50 +4 bytes due to int. +4 due to *boundary.
  struct two *pTwo;                               // &pTwo = 0x7ffe74ad0b58 +8 bytes due to pointer.
  int main_end = 2;                               // &main_end = 0x7ffe74ad0b4c +8 bytes due to pointer.
                                                  // * Pointer addresses on 8 byte boundaries.

  // allocate struct one and its components
  pOne = malloc(sizeof(struct one));
  pOne->start = 1;
  strcpy(pOne->pch, "test");
  pOne->end = 2;
  // values of struct to show they work
  printf("pOne->start = %d\n", pOne->start);
  printf("pOne->pch = %s\n", pOne->pch);
  printf("pOne->end = %d\n", pOne->end);
  // address of variables in main frame
  printf("&main_start = %p\n", &main_start);       // &main_start = 0x7ffe74ad0b48 see above.
  printf("&pOne = %p\n", &pOne);                   // &pOne = 0x7ffe74ad0b50
  printf("&pTwo = %p\n", &pTwo);                   // &pTwo = 0x7ffe74ad0b58
  printf("&main_end = %p\n", &main_end);           // &main_end = 0x7ffe74ad0b4c
  // address of variables in heap
  printf("pOne = %p\n", pOne);                     // pOne = 0x56126b025eb0   addr of struct in heap.
  printf("&(pOne->start) = %p\n", &(pOne->start)); // &(pOne->start) = 0x56126b025eb0. First element is same.
  printf("&(pOne->pch) = %p\n", &(pOne->pch));     // &(pOne->pch) = 0x56126b025eb4 +4 since int
  printf("&(pOne->end) = %p\n", &(pOne->end));     // &(pOne->end) = 0x56126b025ebc +5 since alloc. +3 boundary.


  printf("\n");

  // allocate struct two and its components
  pTwo = malloc(sizeof(struct two));
  pTwo->start = 1;
  pTwo->pch = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
  strcpy(pTwo->pch, "TEST");
  pTwo->end = 2;
  // values of struct to show they work
  printf("pTwo->start = %d\n", pTwo->start);
  printf("pTwo->pch = %s\n", pTwo->pch);
  printf("pTwo->end = %d\n", pTwo->end);
  // address of variables in main frame
  printf("&main_start = %p\n", &main_start);
  printf("&pOne = %p\n", &pOne);
  printf("&pTwo = %p\n", &pTwo);
  printf("&main_end = %p\n", &main_end);
  // address of variables in heap
  printf("pTwo = %p\n", pTwo);                     // pTwo = 0x56126b0262e0  addr of struct in heap
  printf("&(pTwo->start) = %p\n", &(pTwo->start)); // &(pTwo->start) = 0x56126b0262e0 first element is same
  printf("&(pTwo->pch) = %p\n", &(pTwo->pch));     // &(pTwo->pch) = 0x56126b0262e8   +4 int +4 boundary
  printf("&(pTwo->end) = %p\n", &(pTwo->end));     // &(pTwo->end) = 0x56126b0262f0   +8 pointer

  // What I thought OP was doing since I did not read the code well enough.
  // My mistake.
  // struct foo {
  //   int *goo;
  // };
  // struct foo *pFoo;
  // pFoo = malloc(sizeof(foo)*5);
  // Failure since goo is just a pointer.  This is space for 5 foo
  // and the goo pointers are unallocated.
  printf("size of char %ld\n", sizeof(char));
  printf("size of int %ld\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("size of pointer %ld\n", sizeof(int*));

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's continuous"? And in what way is anything that's shown compiler-dependent?

Comment: Huh? There's nothing compiler-dependent here.

Comment: if you have two pointers in that struct of 10 bytes each, do you think both pointers will always point to the same contigous memory?  Perhaps in the array, but between array pointers?  I don't think it guaranteed for all compiler implementations.

Comment: @netskink What you've said doesn't make sense. Different allocations are definitely not expected to be contiguous, but I don't see how that's relevant to this question.

Comment: I was trying to be more clear.  In the example its just one member in struct.  If there are multiple non pointer members in the struct, they will be contiguously allocated.  If there is a pointer in the struct, the storage for the pointer will be in the struct, but the region it points is not necessarily in the same region.

Comment: Tomorrow, I'll demo.  Perhaps I am wrong, but I will do it another time.

Comment: Iron sharpens iron. Man sharpens man.  I appreciate the constructive criticism.